# How to use inet modules in veins simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I want the nodes in my simulation to use AODV protocol to rout packets to the RSU (i don't want the packets to be broadcasted), I know that AODV is implemented in inet but i can't figure out how to use inet models in veins simulation.
I added inet4 and veins_inet the veins sub-project to the workspace but I don't know what to do next I'm using :

`Veins5 Inet4 OMNET-5.5.1`
can anyone help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding Veins 5.0 and its `veins_inet` subproject to your INET simulation (in the IDE: just import both to your workspace, then mark these projects as required for your simulation), you can use Veins as an INET mobility module:

Write your INET simulation as you normally would (e.g., just using random waypoint mobility for your hosts). When you are ready to switch to hosts moving like cars, change their mobility to `VeinsInetMobility`.

Two more changes are required to make this work: first, your simulation must include one module of name `manager` and type `VeinsInetManager`. Second, your hosts must be able to configure their network stack at runtime, which can be done by setting their `networkConfiguratorModule` to `""` and including one module of type `HostAutoConfigurator` in each host.

You can find a complete example of how to write an INET simulation that uses Veins to control host movement at https://github.com/sommer/veins/tree/veins-5.0/subprojects/veins_inet/examples/veins_inet

Comment: I tried to import Veins RSU to veins_inet, do I need to import all other world base utility, connection manager, obstacle modules ? How do I combine these two environments?

Comment: If you use the radio models of the INET Framework, you do not need to use any of the modules you mentioned: they are used solely for the radio models of Veins.